# Hasura connecting to graphql-engine server failed

Tags: graphql, hasura, hasura-docker, hasura-cli

I'm migrating hasura from v1.1 (with config v1) to v2.10 (with config v3).
Locally, I had no issue. I followed [this guide](https://hasura.io/blog/migrating-from-hasura-v1-3-to-v2-0/)

When deploying to test, I can't make it work.
I'm using the `hasura/graphql-engine.v2.9.10.cli-migrations-v3` image. I recreated my database to process from scratch.

I have the following error :

[image]

Test and local env are different on the following points :

- host and ip: (localhost:8080 on local VS classic DNS with 80 port for test env) but I used the `HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT` to override the url with my DNS (for instance HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT=https://my-custom-url.com)
- In local, my db is "default" but its "ebeton-recette" in test env. But my metadata/databases/databases.yaml use

When using the `hasura/graphql-engine.v2.9.10` image (without the suffix) it works and I can apply metadata/migrations using `--endpoint` and `--admin-secret` flags. But I really want the migrations and metadata to be auto applied when deploying...

The "3) Server might me unhealthy..." is indeed true because it fails instantly on deploy...